# What is the correct way to wait for a client response in java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, server-push

First off, if you helped me solve my problem with reading an undefined length HTTP response, I'd like to thank you. I took your advice and switched from HTTP responses to raw Java sockets. But I'm having a little problem with this too.

The nature of a push server is to push things to the client as they are recieved (in my case the system uses a file labeled with the device id.) The problem is that with the KnockKnock example on the Java Tutorials, their code:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {...
```

Waits for the client to send something before sending something itself. So I decided to use:

```
while (true) {
    if ((inputLine=in.readLine())==null) inputLine="";
    ...
```

If any of the input interpereters get this empty string, then they won't do anything.

**My Question** essentially is which one is better and, if it's the first one, how can I keep checking the file to send out what is required without spawning a thread?

Comment: Question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14077960/207421).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one implements the protocol imagined for the KnockKnock example: a client sends "KnockKnock", and the server answers.

The second one doesn't make much sense. If the client has a an output stream open with the server, and the server calls `readLine()`, it means that it's waiting for a line to come from the client. And the call will block until the client sends a line, or closes the socket.

It seems you don't expect any input from the client. In this case, well, don't open an input stream at all, and don't call `readLine()` on the input stream (obviously). Send what you need to send to the client directly, as soon as you want to send it.

Comment: I actually do expect there to be a two way communication (at least for the beginning for the handshake) but after that, it only listens for a command to shutdown the connection: "servicedeath\n"